# What do we usually use when we draw a figure(e.g. shape of neural network) for computer science papers?

Tags: neural-network, figure

I mean when we draw figures like
[image]
and
[image]

what tool do we usually use?

Comment: Where do you need to draw? In latex, images can be imported. There is a s/w in windows: `DIA` that can be used to draw diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "real" graphs you could use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) - this lets you generate the code for your graphs relatively easy from an existing memory-representation.

Otherwise, if you are into LaTeX, I used to use [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) which produces really nice scalable figures, but the learning curve is not that simple and (as you might guess with LaTeX) it is not WYSIWYG.

For WYSIWYG you could of course use the typical Visio, OmniGraffle, ...

P.S.: From the style I would say that the upper graph was produced with Word and the lower one with GraphViz or a LaTeX package

Comment: Call me oldschool but for WYSIWYG I just use Gimp to draw neural networks. I guess everyone has his own method.

Answer (score 0):

you may download some software like Netron [Netron](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/netron)
However, you need the saved format .h5 for the file.
For manual drawing, you may try [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)